# What does diamond operator do when we need one more parameter in generic class?

Tags: java, generics

```
class GenericBase<T> {
    private T baseVariable;
    
    public T get() {
        return baseVariable;
    }
    
    public void set(T t){
        baseVariable = t;
    }
}
class GenericSubTwo<T, V> extends GenericBase<T>{

    private V subVariable2;
    
    public V get2(){
        return subVariable2;
    }
}


public TestClass{

public static void main(String[] args){
GenericBase<Integer> sub2 = new GenericSubTwo<>();
}
}
```

Is it true that diamond operator in this situation actually make new GenericSubTwo<Integer, Integer>();
or maybe something else.. I do not understand what is going on, because in GenericSubTwo I need two parameters..

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is `<Integer, Object>`, though I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 4):

It really doesn't matter, because you cannot see what `V` is anyway.

`V` inferred to be `Object`, since that is the bound on `V`.

**UPDATE**

Actually, it seems `V` is inferred to be `?`, because it can be cast to anything.

```java
GenericBase<Integer> sub2 = new GenericSubTwo<>();

// Valid cast: T must be Integer, but V can be anything
GenericSubTwo<Integer, String> x = (GenericSubTwo<Integer, String>) sub2;
```

Comment: It matter, because you can cast `(GenericSubTwo)sub2`

Comment: @KunLun That is a cast to a **raw** type, so it still doesn't matter, since there is no `V`.

Comment: „*Actually, it seems `V` is inferred to be `?`, because it can be cast to anything...*“ — The ***reference variable*** _`sub2`_ can be „*cast to anything*“. But when I just did _`x.set( "666" )`_ in an experiment to test your example, I get: „_`incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer`_“? Why is that do you think? TIA.

Comment: @deduper 1) `sub2` cannot be cast to *anything*, e.g. is cannot be cast to `GenericSubTwo<String, String>` since `T` **must** be an `Integer`. --- 2) It fails because `T` is `Integer` and the method is `set(T)`, so it has nothing whatsoever to do with this question, which is about `V`.

Comment: Ah! Thx. My bad :) So what's the advantage of (***1***) _`GenericSubTwo<Integer, String> x = (GenericSubTwo<Integer, String>) sub2`_ over (***2***) _`GenericSubTwo<Integer, Object> y = (GenericSubTwo<Integer, Object>) sub2`_? Considering that (***1.a***) _`x.setSubVariable2(666)`_ blows up. But (***2.a***) _`y.setSubVariable2(666)`_  works  fine? (***2.b***) So does _`y.setSubVariable2("666")`_. (***2.c***) Likewise for _`y.setSubVariable2(x)`_? (***2.d***) And even _`y.setSubVariable2(y)`_? Please, can you help me understand the advantage of approach (***1***) over approach (***2***)? TIA.

Comment: 3 hours (*so far*) Andreas? And no response? My _`x`_ versus _`y`_ dilemma got you stumped too, huh? No rush. Whenever you have time. TIA.

Comment: @deduper No response because I was offline (from the world, sleeping). Advantage of #1 is that `get2()` returns a `String`, so no further casting needed, assuming that `V` is supposed to be a string. And if `V` *is* supposed to be a string, a fact that you *acknowledge* when you suppress the **unsafe cast** warning, then it protects against setting the value with an incorrect type. By using #1, you only skirt(?) the type-safety of Java in one place, keeping the rest of the code fully type-safe (or as type-safe as you can get, given that a dumb programmer can cast whenever they want).

Comment: „*Advantage of #1 is that `get2()` returns a `String`, so no further casting needed, assuming that `V` is supposed to be a string.*“ — Oh. OK. Thanks. I thought when you said „*`V` is inferred to be `?`, because **it can be cast to anything***“, that the intention of your answer was to be able  to „*cast to anything*“. Then in the context of being able to „*cast to anything*“, the _`y`_ approach strikes me as a more flexible way to be able to „*cast to anything*“. So could your reply be summarized as „(***1***) *is more type-safe but* (***2***) *is more flexible*“? TIA

Comment: @deduper You're discussing the difference between a `List<String>` and a `List<Object>`, so you're basically asking: what is the benefit of generics. That is entirely *off* topic for this question.

Comment: „*You're discussing the difference between a `List<String>` and a `List<Object>`...*“  — And the ***reason*** I'm discussing that difference is for the ***exact same*** reason @Questw is asking about the difference between _`GenericSubTwo<Integer, Integer>`_, _`GenericSubTwo<>`_ and _`GenericSubTwo<Integer, Object>`_. So to *my* way of thinking, it is absolutely ***on*** topic. But, gentlemen can disagree. Thank you for your time. And sorry my _`x`_ versus _`y`_ dilemma stumped you.

Comment: "Actually, it seems V is inferred to be ?, because it can be cast to anything." The fact that `sub2` can be cast to `GenericSubTwo<Integer, anything>` does not imply anything about the `V` of the `GenericSubTwo` that was assigned to `sub2`. Counterexample: `GenericBase<Integer> sub2 = new GenericSubTwo<Integer, Integer>(); GenericSubTwo<Integer, String> x = (GenericSubTwo<Integer, String>) sub2;` compiles.

Answer (score 1):

> „*Is it true that diamond operator in this situation actually make new GenericSubTwo<Integer, Integer>();*“

No. That's untrue.

> „*or maybe something else*“

Yes. Something else. And that „*something else*“ is *`Object`*. That's because of [*Type Erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

So, the actual parameterized type you'd have would be <strike>*`GenericSubTwo<Object, Integer>()`*</strike> as if you did *`GenericBase<Integer> sub2 = new GenericSubTwo<Integer, Object>()`*.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a philosophical question, because in the compiled bytecode, there is no difference between `new GenericSubTwo<Integer, Object>()`, `new GenericSubTwo<String, String>()`, and `new GenericSubTwo()`. So if you say it uses a particular type argument, but it doesn't affect the result, does it really exist?

Remember that objects do not know their generic type arguments at runtime, so when creating an object at runtime, you do not need to know the generic type arguments. The generic type arguments provided in the `new` are only used at compile-time for type checking purposes (e.g. to check consistency with argument types, if any, and to check if that return type works). After the type checking, those type arguments don't matter anymore, as they are not emitted into the compiled bytecode. In this particular case, since the constructor has no parameters, and the return values is assigned to a `GenericBase<Integer>` where the `V` of `GenericSubTwo<T, V>` is not used, there are no constraints on what `V` can be.

So we can think of different ways the compiler thinks about an object creation expression with the diamond:

- The compiler could try to "infer" some exact type argument for each of the type parameters, and check that that choice works with the arguments and return context; or
- The compiler could try to prove that there exists at least one choice of type argument that would make it compile and make the type checking work, and as long as it can prove that there exists at least one, it does not need to choose which one of them it is, since the actual type argument is not used when emitting the bytecode.